# Linux firefox error: "Unable to draw"

Tags: firefox

When I enter firefox www.google.com on the command line, Linux returns "No display specified". So I type export DISPLAY=:0.

When I next repeat the above firefox command, Linux returns "Unable to draw". What does this error mean and how can I correct it? Am I missing some application for use with Firefox?  Thanks for your help.

Julianloui

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use the terminal? If you are using a system with a GUI, you may use the following command:

```
xdg-open http://www.google.com
```

However, if you have no GUI, you'll either need to install the GUI version, or use

```
wget http://www.google.com
```

and `nano` to read the HTML you get. Not sure why you want this, though.